# Check duplicate before insert Spring Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

How can I validate new entry based on two columns i.e state and period?

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/saveMOH731", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String create(@ModelAttribute("newMOH731")MOH731 moh731, BindingResult result, SessionStatus status)
{
    validator.validate(moh731, result);
    if (result.hasErrors()) 
    {               
        return "newMOH731";
    }
    moh731sDAO.save(moh731);
    status.setComplete();
    return "redirect:viewAllMOH731.do";
}
```

Validator:

```
@Override
public void validate(Object model, Errors errors)
{
    ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "state","required.state", "State is required.");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You can add unique constraint on the property you want to have unique and Spring automatically throws a unique `ConstraintViolationException`. Thereafter you can catch it.
2. Or before saving new entry you can try to find this entry in the database and if you don't find it save or if you find it handle this situation.